# How can I check my python version in cmd?

Tags: python, version

I has downloaded python in python.org, and I wanted to check my python version, so I wrote `python --version` in cmd, but it said just `Python`, without version.  Is there any other way to find out python version?

Comment: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"` will do the trick.

Comment: That is weird that it just says Python, when I run `python --version` I get the exact number, how did you install Python on your computer?

Comment: @MattDMo I usually go with `print(sys.version_info)`

Comment: Are you using bash? If so, what do you get if you type `type python`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A way to do it is to actually start the python interpreter.
You can do that with `python` command. This will start the repl and you will be able to see in the first line something like:

```
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar  8 2021, 13:02:45)
```

Or

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15)
```

Please check in the comments other valid ways to do it.

I am really curious on what is the root cause of your issue tho.

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed python3 then the correct way for checking the version is

**py -3 --version**

You can try running this code in command prompt, anoconda prompt and microsoft power shell.

Answer (score 1):

For Python3 versions enter:

- `python -V` in the command line:
- `py -V`     : print the Python version number and exit (also --version)
  when given twice `-VV`, print more information about the build.
- enter `py -h` to check other parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you typed the `python` command into the cmd and it did not show the currently installed version of py then you may double-check that python is added to your environment variables. (assuming that python is successfully installed on your machine).

Answer (score 0):

use `py --version` command to display the installed Python's version from cmd